# Selenium test to verify css-attribute in style attribute

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

I want to write a selenium IDE test that verifies the value of the bottom attribute in "style" below. How do i write a test for this assuming:

Xpath to the element is: `xpath=/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/a`
I want to use verifyAttribute or similar.

I am using selenium IDE: Command, Target, Value...

```
<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="bottom: 75%; background-color: transparent;"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this would work:

```
COMMAND         | TARGET                 |  VALUE
verifyAttribute | css=input + input@id   |  id
```

Comment: Alternatively xpath-target: //*[@id="myId"]@class

Comment: And to customize for style:  TARGET: **//*[@id="myId"]@style** VALUE: **bottom: 75%; background-color: transparent;**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to use Selenium IDE. Look at your xpath for a simple link, its so complicated and extremely hard to read. If you want to maintain your tests for long run and get ROI write css/xpath on your own. Also use `WebDriver` instead of `Selenium 1.0`. `Selenium 1.0` is in maintenance mode.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http:\\your.site.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);

By findBy = By.cssSelector("a.ui-corner-all")
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(findBy));
String bottom_cssValue = element.getCssValue("bottom");
System.out.println(bottom_cssValue);
```

Comment: I agree with you on this. However, ISO and regulations at my work site prevents me from installing/modifying environment easily, therefore resorting to a firefox plugin makes sense. I am now writing xpaths myself. Much cleaner...